# XMLUNIT - Comparing two xmls with differing Nodes

Tags: xmlunit, xmldiff

I have 2 XMLs to be compared:

File1.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
<member>
    <SchoolID>1021</SchoolID>
    <CandidateType>First Year</CandidateType>
    <CandidateName>John</CandidateName>
</member>
```

File2.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
<member>
    <CandidateID>3147</CandidateID>
    <SchoolID>1021</SchoolID>
    <CandidateType>Second Year</CandidateType>
    <CandidateName>Peter</CandidateName>
</member>
```

I am using xmlunit to compare, however the output I am getting is like:

```
Similar? false
Identical? false
***********************
Expected number of child nodes '2' but was '3' - comparing <member...> at /member[1] to <member...> at /member[1]
***********************
***********************
Expected sequence of child nodes '0' but was '1' - comparing <SchoolID...> at /member[1]/SchoolID[1] to <SchoolID...> at /member[1]/SchoolID[1]
***********************
***********************
Expected text value 'John' but was 'Peter' - comparing <CandidateName ...>John</CandidateName> at /member[1]/CandidateName[1]/text()[1] to <CandidateName ...>Peter</CandidateName> at /member[1]/CandidateName[1]/text()[1]
***********************
***********************
Expected sequence of child nodes '1' but was '2' - comparing <CandidateName...> at /member[1]/CandidateName[1] to <CandidateName...> at /member[1]/CandidateName[1]
***********************
***********************
Expected presence of child node 'null' but was 'CandidateID' - comparing  at null to <CandidateID...> at /member[1]/CandidateID[1]
```

---

I need to represent the output such that it only tells me the following differences:
Node CandidateID is missing in File1.xml and the data difference for Node CandidateName. I don't need the extra details. Is there a way to tweak the output of detDiff.getAllDifferences().

The code snapshot looks like:

```
try {
// fr1 and fr2 are my two xml files.
    Diff diff = new Diff(fr1, fr2); 
    System.out.println("Similar? " + diff.similar());
    System.out.println("Identical? " + diff.identical());

    DetailedDiff detDiff = new DetailedDiff(diff);
    List differences = detDiff.getAllDifferences();
    for (Object object : differences) {
        Difference difference = (Difference)object;
        System.out.println("***********************");
        System.out.println(difference);
        System.out.println("***********************");
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

Depending on your needs you could either filter the differences after the comparison or override the `DifferenceListener` in order to ignore the differences you are not interested in.

For filtering it seems you could just look at `isRecoverable` and strip away all recoverable differences.

A custom `DifferenceListener` would be something like

```
    detDiff.overrideDifferenceListener(new DifferenceListener() {
            @Override
            public int differenceFound(Difference diff) {
                if (diff.getId() == DifferenceConstants.CHILD_NODELIST_SEQUENCE_ID
                    || diff.getId() == DifferenceConstants.CHILD_NODELIST_LENGTH_ID) {
                    return RETURN_IGNORE_DIFFERENCE_NODES_IDENTICAL;
                }
                return RETURN_ACCEPT_DIFFERENCE;
            }
            @Override
            public void skippedComparison(Node arg0, Node arg1) { }
        });
```

before you call `getAllDifferences`.